# Reading from command line during execution

Tags: java, cron

Is there an easy way of passing Linux/Unix commands to Java's `args[]` during program execution? I would like to use Java app with cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM already does that for you:

```
public static int main(String args[]) {...
```

In args[] you will have the command line arguments.

If you want more sofistication (as named parameters, v.g. -title = MyTitle), you can try Apache Command Line Interface(CLI) library.

---

EDIT to answer featon's comment: That will not work, the OS will interpret it as a call to launch a new process. Also, the process name of all java processes is "java" (the OS runs the JVM and does not know what it does in inside).

If what you want is to communicate with a Java process already running, you must open a communication path. Two alternatives are:

- Open a TCP port, launch another application (Java or not) that sends the message there.
- Have the process periodically listing a directory, if any new file appears wait a while (so it is fully created), open it, read it and delete it.

Another path is getting to use J2EE application server that implement functionalities more oriented to Java process that run continuously (even equivalents to cron tasks), but they take some effort to become familiar with.

Comment: Acctualy, I was thinking about  `0 */2 * * *  /home/username/JavaApp arg1` to pass an agrument to already working app. Is is probably the wrong way to do do what I wanted. Now I'm thinking that sth like `0 */2 * * *  /home/username/arg1 >JavaApp` with JavaApp repeatly reading stdin would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks.I think that the other way, similar to TCP port comunication is FIFO special file. Java app needs to read it periodicaly, and and variables could be passed by that file in cron with sth like `0 */2 * * * /home/username/arg1 >FIFOFileName`. Should it work?

Comment: I have never used those; if you find how to read it from java it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have command or two pass it within String[] arguments. If you got more commands, consider putting them in some file and only pass the path to that file as a java program argument.